# Yesod: Stuck in book "Seven Web frameworks in seven weeks"

Tags: haskell, yesod

I installed Yesod according to the [quick start guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart).

I bought the book "Seven Web frameworks in seven weeks" and I'm trying to follow along. I'm on page 204 (Day 1: Working with models). When I enter

```
ghci Model.hs
```

in order to enter some data into the database, as the book says, I get this:

```
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help 
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

Model.hs:3:8:              
    Could not find module ‘ClassyPrelude.Yesod’ 
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.    

Model.hs:4:8:                                   
    Could not find module ‘Database.Persist.Quasi’ 
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm stuck. I'm new to Haskell (but not a newbie) and Yesod, so I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more details for those of us who do not have the book, then we might be able to help you....

Comment: I thought posting text as an image was annoying, but posting text as a video, now *that's* annoying.

Comment: I would suggest you to avoid learning Yesod without getting a grasp of Haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions in this quick start guide led you to create a sandbox for your project, thus the dependencies you installed are only available within this sandbox (which is the cautious and arguably correct way to do it, avoiding collisions and easing the cleanup). GHCi is part of GHC and unaware of the sandbox (which is a concept for and from `cabal` only).

To start an interactive shell in the sandbox launch `cabal repl` from the root directory of your project, then use `:load src/Model.hs` if Model.hs is in src.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have the classy-prelude-yesod package installed. If you have cabal installed, you can easily install any missing package. To do this, you can enter on your OS command prompt the following:

```
cabal install classy-prelude-yesod
```

You can use the same method if you are missing any other packages.

Comment: Use `cabal install --only-dependencies` to install all missing dependencies.

Comment: I did it and it says everything is installed.

Comment: Did you try to install classy-prelude-yesod? Did you get the same error after you installed it?